# buildx call failed with: error: tag is needed when pushing to registry - why are tags in metadata-action not being read by build-push-action?

Tags: docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to create a Github-Actions workflow - [pytorch_error.yml](http://github.com/kusur/learning-audio-processing/blob/main/.github/workflows/pytorch_error.yml) to automatically push Docker images to Docker Hub using Github Actions -

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Building and pushing Docker images to Docker hub

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:  
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [main]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build_push_pytorch_docker_image:
    name: Build and push apex-pytorch-image image to Docker Hub
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Checkout Github repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Log into Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Get Metadata (tags,labels) for Docker images
        id: meta_pytorch
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with: 
          images: kusur/apex-pytorch-image

      - name: Build and push Docker image to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./dockerfile-pytorch
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta_pytorch.ouputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta_pytorch.outputs.labels }}
```

Whenever I execute this code, I get the following error -

```
error: tag is needed when pushing to registry
Error: buildx call failed with: error: tag is needed when pushing to registry
```

While looking at the logs, I see that the tag is being generated at the previous step i.e "Get Metadata (tags,labels) for Docker images" -

```
  with:
    images: ***/apex-pytorch-image
    github-token: ***
Context info
  eventName: workflow_dispatch
  sha: 046137ce5ae09aac18ba44083cd061ac3a37e48a
  ref: refs/heads/main
  workflow: Building and pushing Docker images to Docker hub
  action: meta_pytorch
  actor: ***
  runNumber: 2
  runId: 1090239471
Processing tags input
  type=schedule,pattern=nightly,enable=true,priority=1000
  type=ref,event=branch,enable=true,priority=600
  type=ref,event=tag,enable=true,priority=600
  type=ref,event=pr,prefix=pr-,enable=true,priority=600
Processing flavor input
  latest=auto
  prefix=
  suffix=
Docker image version
  main
Docker tags
  ***/apex-pytorch-image:main
Docker labels
  org.opencontainers.image.title=learning-audio-processing
  org.opencontainers.image.description=Learning Audio Processing
  org.opencontainers.image.url=https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing
  org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing
  org.opencontainers.image.version=main
  org.opencontainers.image.created=2021-08-02T12:39:20.636Z
  org.opencontainers.image.revision=046137ce5ae09aac18ba44083cd061ac3a37e48a
  org.opencontainers.image.licenses=Unlicense
JSON output
  {
    "tags": [
      "***/apex-pytorch-image:main"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "org.opencontainers.image.title": "learning-audio-processing",
      "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Learning Audio Processing",
      "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing",
      "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing",
      "org.opencontainers.image.version": "main",
      "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2021-08-02T12:39:20.636Z",
      "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "046137ce5ae09aac18ba44083cd061ac3a37e48a",
      "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Unlicense"
    }
  }
Bake definition file
  {
    "target": {
      "docker-metadata-action": {
        "tags": [
          "***/apex-pytorch-image:main"
        ],
        "labels": {
          "org.opencontainers.image.title": "learning-audio-processing",
          "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Learning Audio Processing",
          "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing",
          "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/***/learning-audio-processing",
          "org.opencontainers.image.version": "main",
          "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2021-08-02T12:39:20.636Z",
          "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "046137ce5ae09aac18ba44083cd061ac3a37e48a",
          "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "Unlicense"
        },
        "args": {
          "DOCKER_META_IMAGES": "***/apex-pytorch-image",
          "DOCKER_META_VERSION": "main"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but it is not being read by the `build-push-action`. This code is copied from [Publishing Docker Images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/publishing-docker-images). Another file created from this reference is [pytorch_image.yml](https://github.com/kusur/learning-audio-processing/blob/main/.github/workflows/pytorch_image.yml) and this code executes without any issue but the code in question is breaking again and again. I am not able to make out any difference between `pytorch_image.yml` and `pytorch_error.yml` Any help?

Comment: Hey! It is just matter of typo that you've made. You should use `tags: ${{ steps.meta_pytorch.outputs.tags }}` but you've used `tags: ${{ steps.meta_pytorch.ouputs.tags }}`. There is a typo in the `output` word.